# Not able to use BokehJS with Angular8

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, bokehjs

Please find the below error log which i got it in the browser:

AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: FlatBush is not a constructor
    at new SpatialIndex (vendor.js:90501)
    at AnnularWedgeView.push../node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/models/glyphs/xy_glyph.js.XYGlyphView._index_data (vendor.js:104504)
    at AnnularWedgeView.push../node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/models/glyphs/glyph.js.GlyphView.index_data (vendor.js:100363)
    at AnnularWedgeView.push../node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/models/glyphs/glyph.js.GlyphView.set_data (vendor.js:100359)
    at GlyphRendererView.push../node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/models/renderers/glyph_renderer.js.GlyphRendererView.set_data (vendor.js:109490)
    at GlyphRendererView.push../node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/models/renderers/glyph_renderer.js.GlyphRendererView.initialize (vendor.js:109443)
    at GlyphRendererView.View [as constructor] (vendor.js:91313)
    at GlyphRendererView.DOMView [as constructor] (vendor.js:84742)
    at GlyphRendererView.RendererView [as constructor] (vendor.js:109915)
    at GlyphRendererView.DataRendererView [as constructor] (vendor.js:109336)

Answer (score 0):

(Adding some extra info here, I'm new to Bokehjs)

I'm having the same issue, using react with webpack.

```
import * as Bokeh from 'bokehjs'
// ...
Bokeh.embed.embed_item(data_from_backend)
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: FlatBush is not a constructor at new SpatialIndex
```

Doing some debugging..

In `node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/lib/core/util/spatial.js`, changing `this.index = new FlatBush(points.length);` to `this.index = new FlatBush.default(points.length);` makes Bokehjs works.

According to this, I guess it's a module export issue.